# Definition of bipartite graph from Murty-Bondy book

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, definition, bipartite-graphs

I was reading reading the definition of bipartite graph and one moment is confusing me.
Due to this definition we can consider any graph $G=(V,E)$ as a bipartite, if we take $X=\varnothing$ and $Y=V$. However, I am sure that my reasoning is false.

Am I missing something here?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are missing the part that "every edge has one end in $X$ and one end in $Y$."  Unless $G$ has no edges, you cannot have $X=\emptyset$ or $Y=\emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I did not get it why we cannot take on them to be empty set?

Comment: For each edge, one end must appear in $X$ and one end must appear in $Y$, so if $E$ is not empty, then both $X$ and $Y$ contain at least one element.

Comment: Why? The book does not say that $X$ and $Y$ should be non-empty subsets of $V$.

Comment: OK, I'll give you an arbitrary graph, and you exhibit $X$ and $Y$ that satisfy the definition of bipartite.  Take $G=K_3$, the complete graph on $3$ vertices, with $V=\{1,2,3\}$ and $E=\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\}\}$.

Comment: In this case it is not possible. But it sounds probably stupid but I cannot understand the logic here. What if we add in the definition that $X,Y\neq \varnothing$?

Comment: If you specify $X$ and $Y$ nonempty in the definition, the only difference is that you would disallow the empty graphs with $E=\emptyset$ from being called bipartite.

Comment: Let me think about it. But why in the definition of connected graph we consider nonempty partition?

Comment: A small correction: if we specify $X$ and $Y$ nonempty in the definition, then all graphs with $|V|\geq 2, E=\varnothing $ are still bipartite. Then due to this "modified definition" graphs with $|V|\in \{0,1\}$ and $E=\varnothing$ are NOT bipartite.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your correction.

Comment: May I ask you one more question please: why in the definition of connected graphs we require the partitions to be non-empty?

Comment: Please open a new question for that.

Comment: I opened the new question. Please take a look.

Comment: @PlayGame I put in a separate answer for something longer than a comment, but actually if you required nonempty partitions then even a 1 vertex graph with no edges would still not be bipartite, as to partition a 1 vertex graph you'd need 1 of the two sets to be empty

Comment: @Alan He accounted for that with $|V|\in\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @RobPratt 1 doesn't work, you can't partition a 1 element set without one of the two partition sets being empty

Comment: @Alan, right, and that's what PlayGame said.  If $|V|=1$ and $E=\emptyset$ and you require $X$ and $Y$ both nonempty, then $G$ would not be bipartite under that modified definition.

Answer (score 3):

As an additional facet to the other answer,  a graph is bipartite if there is a way of separating the vertices so that every edge connects one part to the other.    Since in modern logic, any universal statement about an empty set is true,   if there are no edges then vacuously it is bipartite no matter the partition you use.

So, we get if the edge set is empty, it is bipartite whether or not we allow the partition to be the trivial one.  If the edge set is nonempty, the trivial partition will not work to demonstrate if it is bipartite or not.  So, the only "advantage" we get of allowing the trivial partition (One set empty, the other the whole space) is we get to consider the fully empty graph:  No vertices, no edges to be bipartite (As the only partition of the empty graph is into two empty sets of vertices).

Since we'd like to include the empty set as bipartite (Vacuously so), we need to allow the empty set to be a partition in this case.

Comment: What about the graph with just one vertex and no edges? That's bipartite, isn't it? In that case, one of the two parts must be the empty set.