# Difference between the definitions of connected and bipartite graphs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, definition, bipartite-graphs

The question which I am about to ask is closely related with [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4395997/definition-of-bipartite-graph-from-murty-bondy-book).

**Question:** In the definition of bipartite graphs we consider partitions $X, Y$ to be any subset of $V$. If we require them to be nonempty, then in this case as far as I understand the graph $G=(V,E)$ with $|V|=0,1$ and $E=\varnothing$ is NOT bipartite. If I am wrong please correct me.

But why in the definition of connected graphs we do require $X,Y$ be nonempty?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you did not require $X$ to be nonempty, then every graph would be disconnected: take $X=\emptyset$ and $Y=V$.

If you did not require $Y$ to be nonempty, then every graph would be disconnected: take $X=V$ and $Y=\emptyset$.

Comment: in the case when we take $X=\varnothing$ and $Y=V$ the graph $G$ is disconnected because for any edge $e\in E$ both its end in $Y$, right?

Comment: Yes, if either end of any edge were in $X$, then $X$ would not be empty.

Comment: Thank you for explanation!

Comment: Hi! can you take a look at this question please?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4401926/proposition-2-9-from-juknas-extremal-combinatorics