# Proposition 2.9 from Jukna's "Extremal Combinatorics"

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I was reading the proof of the following proposition from Jukna's book "Extremal Combinatorics".

[image]

As you see the value of $t$ here cannot be $0$ and $1$. So I guess it is worth to specify that $2\leq t \leq \alpha(G)$.

Is my remark correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your remark is certainly correct, but you could also modify the inequality to
$$
\binom{t}{2}\omega(G) \geqslant dt - n
$$
to keep the cases $t = 0$ and $t = 1$.

Comment: For $t=1$ it is true because $d\leq n$, right?

Comment: @PlayGame Yes, if I got the definition of $d$ right.